# How to run python code a the time I want, from terminal mac Os

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm ratheк new to programming, and my question is rather simple: How to run a bunch of code at time that I want? what I mean is simply how to write a programm or a command in Terminal on macOs (I'm using 10.7) that will run python code at 3 o'clock AM. If python programm lies into:

```
/Users/name/Documents/prog.py
```

To run the programm simply from Terminal I use:

```
cd /Users/name/Documents/
python prog.py 
'hit Enter'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need cron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

> Cron is the time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. Cron enables users to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at certain times or dates.

Comment: Or, if he wants to run once, [`at`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/at.1.html).